# ng-maxlength in placeholder attribute

Tags: angularjs

Is there an easy way for defining a placeholder text for each textbox

in the form of:

"Please enter a maximum of X Chars" where X is the content of ng-maxlength

Or do I have to write it that way manually:

```
<input class="form-control" ng-model="valueBag.test" 
    ng-maxlength="30"
    placeholder="Please enter a maximum of 30 Chars">
```

I have already a form with 30+ existing inputs and I want to add the placeholder to each of them (which would be great to do it not manually).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you could just create a simple directive:

```
app.directive('formControl', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'C',
     link: function(scope, e, attr) {
         var el = e;
         if (attr['ngMaxlength']) {
             el.attr('placeholder', 'Please enter a maximum of ' + attr['ngMaxlength'] + ' Chars')
         }
     }
  }
});
```

This would be applied to any element that has class `form-control` and `ng-maxlength` set.

Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/m1K49L2pHAHaAmfXrrk6?p=preview

You probably could get away with creating an input element directive so the class isn't required:

```
app.directive('input', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
     link: function(scope, e, attr) {
         var el = e;
         if (attr['ngMaxlength']) {
             el.attr('placeholder', 'Please enter a maximum of ' + attr['ngMaxlength'] + ' Chars')
         }
     }
  }
});
```

The angular help docs on directive are now great (not so in the past):  http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

Comment: no need for `angular.element(e)` and `el.hasClass('form-control')`

Comment: You are right, I did that before my morning coffee!